# Can you have a text file in two different directories?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

I have a situation where it would be really convenient if I had a text file that I could edit from two different folders. Here's my attempt at explaining my ideal situation:

Let's call the file `todolist.txt`

`todolist.txt` lives in two different directories `dirA` and `dirB`

No matter which directory I'm in, I can do `nano todolist.txt` and edit/interact with it and it'll be the same when I go to the other directory and want to edit/interact with it.

Is there a way to do this that wouldn't be something weird like having `todolist.txt` in a special hidden directory and only being able to open it through some scripts? Ideally this would be as simple as just defining a text file to exist in two places at once

I use Linux Mint Cinnamon version 19.1

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do this with a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).  The file will ultimately 'live' in one location, but a symbolic link allows you to create a reference to that file anywhere else on your system that behaves as if that file were in two places at once.

If we assume that your file is originally in `dirA`, you can run: `ln -s dirA/todolist.txt dirB/todolist.txt`.  You can now open `todolist.txt` with any software from either location and it will always ultimately open the same file.  No extra tricks or scripts are required, and it's quite a common tool to see used in your system internals.

Answer (score 1):

next time, ask your question at the unix/linux stackexchange.

You are looking for symlinks.
https://linuxhandbook.com/symbolic-link-linux/

These are special files, that point to the same data.
The data lies in one place, but you may reach it by several paths.

If you're actually interested in having the data in two synced places, you'd need to watch it for changes constantly and the copy it afterwords.

Remember: This place is for pragramming questions, only.

Comment: My bad. Thank you.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed. Thank you. Sorry for the wrong post place.